# Logic issue in netlogo

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, netlogo

I am writing this condition:

```
if [estado] of (transmilenios with [xcor = 0.5]) = "vacio" []
```

And im looking at the result in netlogo and i ask the observer:

```
[estado] of (transmilenios with [xcor = 0.5])
```

answer: ["vacio"]

then i ask:

```
[estado] of (transmilenios with [xcor = 0.5]) = "vacio"
```

And the answer is false.

i have a headache with this lol. can someone help me?

I have tried to usea variable estado as 0/1. same answer

```
Estado = "vacio"/"lleno"
```

i have also tried

```
 if [estado] of (transmilenios with [xcor = 0.5]) != "lleno"
```

but it happens the same when estado = "lleno"

Answer (score 1):

In short, `[vacio]` is not equal to `"vacio"`, because `[vacio]` is a list. This issue here is that you are comparing a list to a single value. When you use `of` with an agentset, as you did with `[estado] of (transmilenios with [xcor = 0.5])`, NetLogo returns a list of all the values. Even if you have only a single agent in the queried agentset, it will return a list. How to fix this may depend on what you're modelling. The simplest fix might be to just use `one-of` as a workaround:

`[estado] of (one-of transmilenios with [xcor = 0.5]) = "vacio"`

However, if you're trying to potentially assess multiple `transmilenios` with different values for `estado` then this will not work, as you will only access the `estado` value for a single turtle at a time.

For a working example, consider the following setup:

```
turtles-own [ estado ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 5 [ set estado one-of [ "vacio" "lleno" ] ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

If I `print [estado] of turtles` I get output like: `[lleno vacio lleno lleno vacio]`. So, if I'm comparing `[lleno vacio lleno lleno vacio]` to `vacio` then the answer is clearly false.

If I instead `print [estado] of one-of turtles` I get either `lleno` or `vacio` as an output- so evaluating `print [estado] of one-of turtles = "vacio"` will return either true or false.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Perfectly explained! Thank you very much